# How can I choose an option from a fgets input in C?

Tags: c, fgets

So I have this code:

```
  printf("S: Search\n");
  printf("A: Add\n");
  printf("D: Delete\n");
  printf("Q: Quit\n");
  printf("\nYour choice: ");

  while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, stdin) && once == 1)
  { 
    printf("Option: %s\n", line);
    once++;
  }
```

And here comes where I'm struggling:

```
  if (line == 's')
  {
    printf("option s function here");
  } else if (line == 'a')
  {
    printf("option a function here...");
  } /* and so on */
```

This is not working and I've been trying to fix it but nothing I tried worked. How can I write that last piece of code in order to be able to select an option from the fgets input?

Comment: `if (line[0] == 's')` will check whether the first character of the line is `'s'`. You might want to accept uppercase as well, since the prompt shows uppercase options. In that case, `if (line[0] == 's' || line[0] == 'S')` allows upper or lower case.

Comment: What do you want your code to do if someone enters "silly" instead of "s"?

Comment: @JeffHolt I'm not thinking about errors now, I'm just assuming that the input will be always correct

Comment: @user3386109 if I try to printf line[0] it says segmentation fault

Comment: You'll want to show the printing code otherwise only an educated guess would tell you why your code is causing a SIGSEGV.